# OFFSET an array

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using this formula to extract values from another sheet if certain criteria are met:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("BLABLABLA", "Form Responses 1!A6:X"),"SELECT * WHERE Col4 <> '' AND Col2 = 'CONTENT' AND Col21 <> 'yes'")
```

What I'd like to do is display the content starting from column `D` of the input sheet. I can't "truncate" the `IMPORTRANGE` doing `D6:X` because I have a criteria for the `QUERY` referring to column B.

The dirty hack I'm using right now is just changing the offset number for each row where I want the output:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("BLABLABLA", "Form Responses 1!A6:X"),"SELECT * WHERE Col4 <> '' AND Col2 = 'CONTENT' AND Col21 <> 'yes'"),,4)

=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("BLABLABLA", "Form Responses 1!A6:X"),"SELECT * WHERE Col4 <> '' AND Col2 = 'CONTENT' AND Col21 <> 'yes'"),,5)

=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("BLABLABLA", "Form Responses 1!A6:X"),"SELECT * WHERE Col4 <> '' AND Col2 = 'CONTENT' AND Col21 <> 'yes'"),,6)
```

But it's a pain and I'm sure there's a way to output from the first formula directly the content only from column D to X (but still being able to use column B as a criterion for the `QUERY` function).

I had a look at the `OFFSET` function, but it seems it just outputs single cells, and doesn't expand an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using another query () ?

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("BLABLABLA", "Form Responses 1!A6:X"),"SELECT * WHERE Col4 <> '' AND Col2 = 'CONTENT' AND Col21 <> 'yes'"),"SELECT Col4, Col5, Col6")
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works! Is there a way to say `"SELECT Col4 to Col20"`, without having to put every column `"SELECT Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8"` ?